# css of nav-item not correctly applied after screen resize

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

After resizing the screensize the nav-link buttons don't use the css i gave them anymore. I tried the @media function but it doesn't react on changes in the css after resizing the screen.
(tables are empty, they get filled by the JS code.)

Why is itn't it responding or using the css after resizing the screen?

[before resizing (large screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykZys.png)

[after resizing (smaller screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0kCW.png)

In the picture below you can see that there is some interfering with the code but i don't use the @media function at all but it's still using it.

[what the browser is seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZbY9.png)

```css
.annuHypoTabellen .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #ff486dad;
  color: #fff;
}

.annuHypoTabellen  .nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  background-color: #de002e;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.annuHypoTabellen .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  background-color: rgba(201, 201, 201, 0.425);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #616161;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
                        <div class="annuHypoTabellen mt-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-9 col-12">
                                <h4 class="text-gtdirect mt-3 mb-3">
                                    Overzicht totale lasten bij <ins>niet</ins> oversluiten
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 col-12 ml-auto d-flex justify-content-end ">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 navHypoTabsSmall" id="huidigeHypoTab" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link nav-link-annuHypo active" id="pills-jaarHuidigeHypo-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-jaarHuidigeHypo" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-jaarHuidigeHypo" aria-selected="true">Per Jaar</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link nav-link-annuHypo" id="pills-maandHuidigeHypo-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-maandHuidigeHypo" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-maandHuidigeHypo" aria-selected="false">Per Maand</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="swipeIcons mb-2">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col">
                                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-lg float-left text-gtdirect pt-1"></i>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-center lead">Scroll</h5>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col">
                                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right fa-lg float-right text-gtdirect pt-1"></i>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-jaarHuidigeHypo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-jaarHuidigeHypo-tab">
                                <div class="anhypoResult">
                                    <div class="scrollBox">
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th scope="col">Jaar</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">Totale jaar rente</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">Totale jaar aflossing</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">Schuld ultimo</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">Eigen-woning-forfait</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">IB-EWF</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">IB rente aftrek</th>
                                                        <th scope="col">Netto lasten</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody class="annuHuidigeHypoResultTabelJaar">
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-maandHuidigeHypo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-maandHuidigeHypo-tab">
                                <div class="anhypoResult">
                                    <div class="scrollBox">
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">Jaar</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Maand</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Rente</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Aflossing</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Schuld ultimo</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Eigen-woning-forfait</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">IB-EWF</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">IB rente aftrek</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Netto lasten</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                    <tbody class="annuHuidigeHypoResultTabel">
                                                    </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Does your browser have cache enabled? I've found that this can be a problem

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other css that could interfere? Something like bootstrap for example?

Comment: Considering you're using Bootstrap v4, this cannot possibly have anything to do with the `resize` event. That is to say you're not going to get a different result if you load the page wide and resize it small than you would if you just loaded the page small. That being said, please create a [mcve] so we can actually pinpoint the cause of your button having the default `primary` color instead of the one you want. What you provided so far ***does not reproduce*** the issue, so you haven't included the source of the bug yet.

Comment: @J'hacklelezard there is something interfering with a media function but i don't use that function on that code.

Comment: @tao the amount of code i really large, https://algemeen.gtdienst.nl/anhypo.html this is the webpage so far

Comment: That's not helpful at all. First of all, not even the live page doesn't reproduce the issue (I don't see the button). Second of all, you're supposed to create a [mcve]. Minimal meaning: the least amount of code to reproduce the issue. Just make a snippet with the HTML and the CSS applying at that particular step. Note linking a live website is not helpful for any future users with a similar problem, as you're gonna fix it on the live server, at which point your question will no longer be helpful for others so, by [SO] standards, it shouldn't be answered.